# "Missing file name header" error appears when I open a file sen't from Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, file, servlets, inputstream

We have a java web application, in which there is a functionality to download an executable file (.exe). When I opened the file downloaded at **client side**, the error occurs stating "Missing file name header" and can't run the file.

I am using below code to send the file to client.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getExecutableFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void executeAssetCoreAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
 InputStream in = getTheFileStream();

 response.setContentType("application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + "console.exe" + "\"");
 response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", DateTime.now().getMillis());
 IOUtils.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), response.getOutputStream());
 in.close();
}
```

- Where IOUtils is apache commons lib

Comment: One note here is, The file is being downloaded with the name console.exe but still it's giving "missing file name header" error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + "console.exe" + "\"");
```

to:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\" + "console.exe" + "\");
```

It looks like you may have been asking for filename of ( + "console.exe" + "\") instead of ("console.exe")

Comment: Changing it with your solution giving Syntax error. I have also tried changing it to "attachment; filename=\"console.exe\"", But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The description of your client behavior would be welcome

the client code and necessary to check your header.

on the sending side of the file I would not do it that way, even if it that way, even if it looks ok.

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

out.write(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.getPath("your path")));
```

Java.nio.file

Check IOException while a reading